# ¿Hay alguna alternativa sintáctica en esta query?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que esto es una solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra alternativa, más en concreto, a la hora de formular la sintaxis para la fecha en que era director el empleado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pregunto si hay alguna forma de formular lo mismo utilizando otra sintaxis.

Comment: Por favor todo lo que sea código como texto

Comment: Gracias, esto era lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el operador [BETWEEN](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_between.asp) puedes hacerlo

*Nota: OJO con los rangos siempre debes comprobar si los rangos son inclusivos o no, el `BETWEEN` toma ambos rangos inclusivamente, debes comprobar si lo datos en tu base de datos son así, asumo por tu consulta inicial que lo son, ya que agregaste <= y >=*

```
select emp_no from dept_manager where '1990-01-01' BETWEEN from_date and to_date
```